# Looping through array of objects is only returning one object of elements instead of two. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Forewarning I am new to coding so be patient with me.

I'm trying to loop through the "diary" array & the function "howMany" is only returning 2 'Home' elements, when there are 4 elements of 'Home' overall in the "diary" array.

[Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJrMq.png)

What am I doing wrong? Thank you. :)

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, as text, formatted as a code block, rather than a link to a picture of text.

Comment: I tried, but I kept getting an error that it wasn't formatted properly. I couldn't figure out how to properly format the embedded code in the text, im new to this.

Comment: There's a FAQ and formatting help during question entry, and help in the editor itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `includes` method which only returns the boolean. If it's matched, even got 4 matches, the `number` only will be increased by 1 for each loop.

This is another way to achieve that by using `filter`.

```
let diary = [];

const addEntry = (events) => {
  diary.push({ events });
};

addEntry(['Home', 'Work', 'Park', 'Beach', 'Home']);
addEntry(['Work', 'Home', 'Store', 'Gas Station', 'Home']);

const howMany = (event, journal) => {
  let number = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    let entry = journal[i];
    number += entry.events.filter((e) => e === event).length;
  }

  console.log(`You did that ${number} time(s)`);
};

howMany('Home', diary);
console.log(diary);
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter*

---

##### Update: Using `reduce` & `filter`.

```
let diary = [];

const addEntry = (events) => {
  diary.push({ events });
};

addEntry(['Home', 'Work', 'Park', 'Beach', 'Home']);
addEntry(['Work', 'Home', 'Store', 'Gas Station', 'Home']);

const howMany = (event, journal) =>
  journal.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc + curr.events.filter((e) => e === event).length,
    0
  );

const number = howMany('Home', diary);

console.log(`You did that ${number} time(s)`);    
console.log(diary);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd argue creating a new array for counting might not be the best approach when a loop or reduce avoids it.

Comment: Thank you, this helped achieve what I was looking for. Im reading through Eloquent Javascript and the example in the text utilized the includes method so I tried recreating my own exercise but I didn't know that's how the includes method worked specifically. Thank you so much!

Comment: @baphomet It's almost always a good idea to check out the documentation for unfamiliar functions first.

Comment: For sure. This is like my second day coding & I'm self learning, so I'm about as green as green could be. What do you mean by the documentation for unfamiliar functions? @DaveNewton

Comment: @baphomet I mean read the docs :) Similar to the docs for "filter" in this answer, "includes" also has docs (as does essentially everything else). I encourage people to get familiar early with relevant docs (and occasionally just scanning them for the lolz--you never know what you'll find :)

Comment: I've updated the new answer using `reduce` & `filter` methods.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for earlier answer i didnt review the code this is the correct one

```js
let diary = [];

const addEntry = (event) => {
  diary.push(event);
};

addEntry(['Home', 'Work', 'Park', 'Beach', 'Home']);
addEntry(['Work', 'Home', 'Store', 'Gas Station', 'Home']);

const howMany = (event, journal) => {
  let number = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    for(let j =0;j < journal.length;j++) {
    const entries = journal[i][j]
     if(event.includes(event)){
      number++
     }
    }
   
  }

  console.log(`You did that ${number} time(s)`);
};

howMany('Home', diary);
console.log(diary);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it returning only two is because `includes()` method will not count on how many occurrence of it occur, but only return boolean. And your code only count how many `true` statement is occur. In your case, because the array length is 2 and every element happens to have 'Home', your code only returning 2.

There are multiple way to achieve what you want but what I do below is to use multiple `foreach` (or you can use for loop as well) kinda like checking 2d array.

```
let diary = []

const addEntry = events =>{
    diary.push({events})
}

addEntry(['Home', 'Work', 'Park', 'Beach', 'Home'])
addEntry(['Work', 'Home', 'Store', 'Gas Station', 'Home'])

const howMany = (event, journal) => {
    let number = 0;
  journal.forEach(element => {
    element.events.forEach(item => {
      if (item === event) {
        number++
      }
    })
  });
  console.log(`You did that ${number} time(s)`);
}

howMany('Home', diary)
console.log(diary)
```

*sorry if my english is pretty bad.